# Why does Samba4 fail with NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, samba, domain-controller, samba4, ubuntu-18.04

I am having trouble setting up Samba as an AD DC. At present I have 1 Ubuntu box which I’d like to use to share files with other computers in my home network. At present the same machine which servers as the DC would also serve the files.

This is a home setup, meaning that I am using a consumer-grade router.

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Samba: Version 4.7.6-Ubuntu

To begin each iteration of my attempts to get it working I perform the recommended steps to kill any samba processes etc and remove the files discussed in *Preparing the Installation* from the setup guide https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller

```
$ ps ax | egrep "samba|smbd|nmbd|winbindd"
```

I then kill all processes as described.

I verify that samba is installed

```
$ which samba
/usr/sbin/samba
$ samba --version
Version 4.7.6-Ubuntu
```

The instructions also read

> Verify that the /etc/hosts file on the DC correctly resolves the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) and short host name to the LAN IP address of the DC. For example:

The exact contents are

```
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain
192.168.1.1     DC1.samdom.example.com DC1


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Note that the Ubuntu box’s IP on the local network is `192.168.1.20` `192.168.1.1` is the LAN IP found on my router under the LAN tab and IP Address field. Note I do not have DDNS turned on for my router.

```
$ sudo samba-tool domain provision --use-rfc2307 --interactive
Realm: SAMDOM.EXAMPLE.COM
 Domain [SAMDOM]: SAMDOM
 Server Role (dc, member, standalone) [dc]: dc
 DNS backend (SAMBA_INTERNAL, BIND9_FLATFILE, BIND9_DLZ, NONE) [SAMBA_INTERNAL]: SAMBA_INTERNAL
 DNS forwarder IP address (write 'none' to disable forwarding) [192.168.1.1]: 8.8.8.8
Administrator password:
Retype password:
Looking up IPv4 addresses
Looking up IPv6 addresses
No IPv6 address will be assigned
Setting up share.ldb
Setting up secrets.ldb
Setting up the registry
Setting up the privileges database
Setting up idmap db
Setting up SAM db
Setting up sam.ldb partitions and settings
Setting up sam.ldb rootDSE
Pre-loading the Samba 4 and AD schema
Adding DomainDN: DC=samdom,DC=example,DC=com
Adding configuration container
Setting up sam.ldb schema
Setting up sam.ldb configuration data
Setting up display specifiers
Modifying display specifiers
Adding users container
Modifying users container
Adding computers container
Modifying computers container
Setting up sam.ldb data
Setting up well known security principals
Setting up sam.ldb users and groups
Setting up self join
Adding DNS accounts
Creating CN=MicrosoftDNS,CN=System,DC=samdom,DC=example,DC=com
Creating DomainDnsZones and ForestDnsZones partitions
Populating DomainDnsZones and ForestDnsZones partitions
Setting up sam.ldb rootDSE marking as synchronized
Fixing provision GUIDs
A Kerberos configuration suitable for Samba AD has been generated at /var/lib/samba/private/krb5.conf
Setting up fake yp server settings
Once the above files are installed, your Samba AD server will be ready to use
Server Role:           active directory domain controller
Hostname:              zoo-vault
NetBIOS Domain:        SAMDOM
DNS Domain:            samdom.example.com
DOMAIN SID:            …
```

Great, so far so good. I copy the `krb5.conf` file as suggested to /etc/krb5.conf.

I skip the **Setting up the AD DNS back end** as I am using `SAMBA_INTERNAL`

My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search samdom.example.com
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

I skip **Create a reverse zone** and then copy the kerberos file as suggested.

This is where it goes wrong. I’ve started samba with `sudo samba`, the processes look like they are running but any of the following verification commands given in the documentation do not work.

```
$ smbclient //localhost/netlogon -UAdministrator -c 'ls'
Enter SAMDOM\Administrator's password:
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
$ host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.samdom.example.com.
Host _ldap._tcp.samdom.example.com. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
$ host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.samdom.example.com.
Host _kerberos._udp.samdom.example.com. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
$ host -t A dc1.samdom.example.com.
Host dc1.samdom.example.com. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

I’m at somewhat of a loss here.

A few things to note. My ubuntu machine’s static IP on my local network is NOT 192.168.1.1 (the IP I used in the config steps above). It is 192.168.1.20. I’ve tried using that IP as well, to no avail.

I have also tried using `none`, `192.168.1.1` and `8.8.8.8` as the `DNS forwarder IP address` during setup to no avail.

I have found some articles online variously offering solutions or further test functions but have yet to find anything that solves my problem.

In the end I would like to set up Samba to function as a

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that all dependencies listed for your OS on the samba website are properly installed.
2. Be sure that the IP address used in `/etc/hosts` is that of the machine itself and not a router or some other hardware.
3. Use the same IP in `/etc/resolv.conf` as well.
4. In `/etc/hosts` the name of the machine in the example is `DC1.` This name should match the name of the machine for the latter commands to work. If your machines name is `DC1` you're all set otherwise replace `DC1` with the name of your machine.
5. In order to ensure continued internet access once Samba has started use a DNS IP you have access to when prompted for the 'DNS forwarder IP address'. This may require that you use your router's LAN IP.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Samba on Debian 9 only with

```
apt install samba
```

and got the same failure. Had to add winbind (and smbclient)

```
apt install winbind
```

Answer (score -1):

install winbind

```
sudo apt install winbind
```

this solve the problem for me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that and was unable to get it to work on its own.